# iOS 7 update failed - stuck on Connect to iTunes

Tags: itunes, ios

I was downloading iOS 7 to my iPhone 4 and the update was going for almost 1 day. I left it overnight and when I was about to use my phone it is stuck on the 'Connect to iTunes' screen (iTunes logo with a USB cord). My phone is still stuck on that and when I try to fix it with iTunes with my PC (Windows 7) the message always pops up saying that my phone needs to restore. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Did you start the update from a download to iTunes or an over the air update? That might help, better step in troubleshooting, can you use iTunes to initiate a restore now that it is stuck?

Answer (score 1):

When your phone gets stuck trying to update, it usually means it has way too much data in it. For a good average update that's takes at least 20 mins, you'll need to have at least 2.5 GB. Your phone has gotten stuck because it had way too much stuff in it, and it can't continue.

My solution: restore the phone. There is way too much data inside,and it will stay that way unless something happens. This can be a good and bad thing. If you had some stuff on iCloud or some storage, you just might restore your apps and everything else. But if you don't, let's just hope you had nothing important in the phone, because it might just go down the drain. Besides you are left with no other option, right?

I hope this helps. If you find a better way, please use that way instead of this way. I hope you are able to fix your phone.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to solve this is to actually restore your iPhone.